# Using two monitors : How to expand to full screen in one monitor only ?

Tags: java, swing, fullscreen

I'm developing a java desktop application which I need to go on full screen. I'm developing on Debian with extended desktop, two monitors, so when the application starts it goes all over the width of the two monitors. Just wondering if anyone could help me with some tips or a way to do the app go full screen just in one desktop.

Here's the way I'm actually using, is in the constructor of the class:

```
    Toolkit tk= Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    int xsize, ysize;
    xsize = (int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth();
    ysize = (int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight();
    this.setSize(xsize, ysize);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Full screen mode? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you posted I'm guessing you don't really want fullscreen. When you use fullscreen there are no borders or title bar and fullscreen takes the entire screen so you don't need to specify the size.

Your code looks like it is just trying to set the size of a JFrame. I don't use 2 monitors but to size a frame to a single monitor you should be using:

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

and don't play with the size manually. Maybe this will also work with a dual monitor?

Comment: Checking the code and trying as suggested, I realized that the windows now goes on full screen just in one desktop, that after I tried extendedState. No way could be that change 'cause I have returned to my  original code after compiled, the only thing that its different is an update I made yesterday to my OS and IDE. Guess is one of that mysteries of life.. but thanks I'll be working just like this.